# Multiple Access Levels to an Article

Tags: joomla-4.x, acl, user-groups, access, joomla-user-groups

We have a case in which we have created more than 30 user groups and we need more than 50 access levels for different articles or menus.

I have estructured my ACL like this.

Groups like:

- Group1

  - Subgroup11
  - Subgroup12
- Group2

  - Subgroup21
  - Subgroup22
  - Subgroup23
- ...
- Group N

  - ...

Access levels like this:

- AL1 (Subgroup11)
- AL2 (Subgroup11, Subgroup12)
- AL3 (Subgroup11, Subgroup21)
- AL4 (Subgroup21, Subgroup23)
- AL5 (Subgroup12, Subgroup21, Subgroup23)
- AL6 (Subgroup12, Subgroup21, Subgroup22, Subgroup23)
- ...

Is there a way to reduce this by being able to select multiple access levels for an article or menu? Is there a way to be able to directly select which groups can see an article or menu option without needing to select access levels?

Any solution with the Joomla core or also an extension would be good.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you expand your question to show a sample of how you have structured your ACL so far. You can't select multiple view levels for a single article however you maybe able to structure your ACL differently so that you can achieve what you you need.

Comment: I have updated my question with the information you requested. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ability, via core or a 3rd party extension, to provide you with the ability to have multiple view groups specified in an Article, Category or Menu. Understanding how the View level is used by the and 3rd party extensions being able to have multiple view levels would be a fundamental shift in how Joomla does access control so I suspect that it is not something likely to be introduced either.

You may find one or two extensions in JED that make it easier for you to manage a large set of User Groups and View levels however you will only have one view level that you can define.

Your additional information provided in the question, thank you, doesn't provide any context around what you are trying to manage, e.g. departments in a company or something else, therefore my following comments are going to be more general in nature.

In a simple Joomla environment you find a one to one relationship arrangement between usergroups and view levels. In your question your example shows a hierarchical arrangement of Usergroups and view levels which tend to suit organisational structures with departments etc.

A third arrangement is to have a roles based or responsibilities structure to your ACL where access is granted by what need or role they play that requires access to the content rather than a hierarchical or departmental structure.

A good article that describes this approach can be found here, https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/september-2012/implementing-role-based-acl and although written for Joomla 3 it is not something confined to Joomla nor organisation structures, I have worked with this in other areas of IT security. With some thinking and planning it can be useful for subscription based access and other requirements.

In your question you need to move the mindset from having multiple view levels in an article to having multiple usergorups per a single view level.

Whether it means less user groups and view levels for you or more complexity that will come down to your requirements and implementation in the context of what you are trying to achieve.